# Why the Bingo game doesn't stop after guessing correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create the Bingo game in object oriented form but it has a bug that it doesn't stops the game when one player guesses correctly or they ran out of guesses.
What can I do?

```
import random


class Game:
    player_list = []

    def __init__(self):
        self.rand_num = random.randint(1, 20)
        self.name = input("Enter your name: ")
        self.guess_left = 3
        self.win_stats = False
        Game.player_list.append(self)

    def check_answer(self):
        answer = int(input(f'{self.name} guess a number: '))
        if answer > self.rand_num:
            print("Guess lower")
        elif answer < self.rand_num:
            print("Guess higher")
        elif answer == self.rand_num:
            print("Bingo!")
            self.win_stats = True
        self.minus_guess_left()
        print(f"{self.name} you have {self.guess_left} guesses left")

    def minus_guess_left(self):
        self.guess_left -= 1

    def has_guess_left(self):
        if self.guess_left > 0:
            return True
        return False

    def has_won(self):
        return self.win_stats

    @classmethod
    def game_has_winner(cls):
        if any(player.has_won() is True for player in cls.player_list):
            return True
        return False


class GameController:
    def __init__(self):
        while True:
            for player in Game.player_list:
                if not player.has_won():
                    player.check_answer()
            if Game.game_has_winner():
                break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        order = input("What is your order: ")
        if order == 'add':
            Game()
        elif order == 'start':
            GameController()
        elif order == 'exit':
            break
```

```
What is your order: add
Enter your name: alex
What is your order: add
Enter your name: john
What is your order: start
alex guess a number: 10
Guess higher
alex you have 2 guesses left
john guess a number: 10
Guess higher
john you have 2 guesses left
alex guess a number: 15
Bingo!
alex you have 1 guesses left
john guess a number: 15
Guess lower
john you have 1 guesses left
What is your order:
```

This is the output that it keeps playing after the guess correctly

Comment: FYI, this game isn't [Bingo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bingo_(American_version))

Comment: You never call `has_guess_left()`, so it won't stop when someone runs out of guesses.

Answer (score 1):

You don't check for a winner until after the loop that allows both players to guess. Move that check inside the `for player in Game.player_list` loop.

You also need to call `player.has_guess_left()` before asking for a guess from the player.

There's no need to call `player.has_won()` before asking for a guess, since we'll exit the game when someone has won.

```
class GameController:
    def __init__(self):
        while any(player.has_guess_left() for player in Game.player_list):
            for player in Game.player_list:
                if player.has_guess_left():
                    player.check_answer()
                if Game.game_has_winner():
                    return
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you check if the game has a winner only in `GameController` class, but you need to do that also in the main code block because there is an infinite loop too.

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        ...
        elif order == 'start':
            GameController()
            if Game.game_has_winner():
                break
            if Game.all_lost():
                print('You all lose')
                break
        ...
```

For checking if all players have no any guesses you could implement the `Game` class method similar to existing `game_has_winner`:

```py
@classmethod
def all_lost(cls):
    if not any(player.has_guess_left() for player in cls.player_list):
        return True
```

Also, you should use your `has_guess_left` method as @Barmar described in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77174597/22561467).